# Remove query parameter when performing HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

When i redirect using sendRedirect function, i see that the original query params are added to the URL.

How can i avoid it and remove the query parameters from the redirected URL?

My code is:

```
response.sendRedirect(ApplicationUtils.getServerConfig().homePageLink);

return;
```

Comment: Just build the `location` url without them.

Comment: They aren't added automatically by the servlet API. Show us your code.

Comment: They are. I added my code

Comment: I see when it happening, but not sure why. It happens when there is a # as part of the query string

Comment: As @JBNizet said, `sendRedirect` doesn't add query params. So check what your `homePageLink` contains.

Comment: homePageLink does not contain any query params. As i said, the query params are always appended if it originally contained #. everything after the # is appended

Comment: What is after the # is not a query param, but a hash or anchor. And it's not added by sendRedirect(). Tell us more about your environment. You might have a filter that automatically appends the hash.

Comment: Agreed to all the comments above, sendRedirect does not append any request parameters. It must be something else. I have tested this. I'd recomment you debug homePageLink just before you redirect to see what's in there

Comment: +1 to a filter causing this, or something container/framework specific. Put a breakpoint where you're doing the redirect and check the class of the response you get. It should give an indication if something has wrapped it. Also, check the actual headers when they arrive the browser. Maybe something is doing it client side, although unlikely, since it's a redirect. But you never know.